# Hadoop put command doing nothing!

Tags: apache, hadoop, cloudera

I am running Cloudera's distribution of Hadoop and everything is working perfectly.The hdfs contains a large number of .seq files.I need to merge the contents of all the .seq files into one large .seq file.However, the getmerge command did nothing for me.I then used cat and piped the data of some .seq files onto a local file.When i want to "put" this file into hdfs it does nothing.No error message shows up,and no file is created.

I am able to "touchz" files in the hdfs and user permissions are not a problem here.The put command simply does not work.What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Write a job that merges the all sequence files into a single one. It's just the standard mapper and reducer with only one reduce task.

Comment: I can do that,however this particular situation is puzzling me.Why is the "put" command not doing anything.Its not even giving me an error message!

Comment: Tried -copyFromLocal too, even that is not working.Same issue,no error message and no file created/copied.I would like to inform about another issue.Usually,when we type just "hadoop" at Bash, it either gives the help information or gives an error message if the environment variable is not set.However in this case too,typing "hadoop" does nothing.Absolutely nothing.Bash quietly comes to the next prompt.Are the two issues part of the same problem?

Answer (score 0):

if the "hadoop" commands fails silently you should have a look at it.

Just type: 'which hadoop', this will give you the location of the "hadoop" executable. It is a shell script, just edit it and add logging to see what's going on.

If the hadoop bash script fails at the beginning it is no surprise that the hadoop dfs -put command does not work.